# paymentwall integration with android app

Tags: android, in-app-billing, paymentwall

i am new to android and i am developing an android application in which i am trying to integrate in-app credits using **paymentwall** but their provided information is not enough for a beginner.

first user will buy some credit via mobile carrier billing than that credit will further be used in the in-app purchasing

https://www.paymentwall.com/en/

i need a full step by step guideline.

Comment: https://www.paymentwall.com/en/documentation/Mobiamo-Android-SDK/2995

Comment: i've read this but further after this i am not clear what to do next

Comment: did you produced something at the end ? their documentation contains many errors, mistyped functions and missing some information which is not organized in one place.